# azure queue triggered webjob prevent message dequeue from azure queue

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-queues

I have azure webjob triggers from azure queue. i don't want to dequeue message on some specific condition, and i would like to process that message after some time for example (5 minutes) is it possible to prevent dequeue message ?

Comment: You can not read message without dequeuing it. You should use another queue for that specific condition. you can dequeue message from first queue and insert in into another queue for that specific condition.

Comment: use peekmessage() insted of getmessage() so that way you can read messages without dequeuing it

Answer (score -1):

You can set the invisibility timeout when you add a message (or via update message API) - this prevents the message from being seen by clients. Would that help?